# MediaWiki: How to update a link status programmatically

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

My extension renders additional links on a page (that is adds some `<a href='...'>...</a>` to the page text (in `HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd` hook)).

See small arrows in https://withoutvowels.org/wiki/Tanakh:Genesis_1:1 for an example. The arrows are automatically added by my extension (sorry, at the time of writing this the source code is not yet released).

The problem is that red/blue ("new") status is not updated for links which I add.

Please explain how to make Wikipedia to update color of my links as appropriate together with regular `[[...]]` MediaWiki links.

My current workaround is to run `php maintenance/update.php`. It is a very bad workaround. How to do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With valuable help of Wikitech-l mailing list, I found a solution.

The solution is to use ParserAfterTidy hook.

```
public static function onParserAfterTidy( &$parser, &$text ) {
            # ...

            $parserOutput = $parser->getOutput();

            foreach($parserOutput->getLinks() as ...) {
                    # ...

                    $parserOutput->addLink( Title::newFromDBkey(...) );
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd use `LinkRenderer` to create the links and `LinkBatch` to make the page existence check efficient (you don't want a separate SQL query for each link). You can't really do that in `HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd` since you only learn about the links one by one.

The way the parser deals with this is that it replaces links with a placeholder and collects them in a list, then after parsing is mostly done it looks them all up at once and then switches the placeholders with the rendered links. You can probably hook into somthing that happens between the two (e.g. `ParserAfterParse`), get the list of links from the parser and use them to build a list of your own links.

Comment: Hm, there is something like this `parser/LinkHolderArray.php`

Comment: But does your solution solve my main problem: How to make it known to MediaWiki engine about links I add, so that it would re-render my page as necessary to switch between red/blue links?

Comment: Why would the engine have to know about your links? If you are worried about them not showing up in `Special:WhatLinksHere` and the like, you can fix that in one of the `LinksUpdate`-related hooks.

Comment: It seems that `LinksUpdate` does the opposite thing of what I need: it updates the links in the saved document, while I need to update links to the saved document. How?!

Comment: No, `LinksUpdate` updates links to the saved document (so e.g. red links can become blue when the linked article is created).

Comment: ```
 public static function onLinksUpdateConstructed( LinksUpdate &$updater ) {
                wfDebugLog( 'namespacepopups', var_dump_ret($updater->mLinks) );
```

This tracing show the links **in** the updated document, not **to** the updated document.

Comment: Sure, those are needed to e.g. remove the linked articles from the list of orphan pages (if previously nothing linked to them). I'm not really familiar with this part of the code but I think what you need is the `SecondaryDataUpdates` hook, and then create a new `ParserOutput`, add your generated links to it, create an additional `LinksUpdate` from that and add it to `$updates`.

Comment: It seems that no: `LinksUpdate` objects contain `$mLinks` fields which contains (I tested) the list of links in the document not the list of incoming links. Thus it is not what I need :-(